# How to store bytes or values in the most compact way?

Tags: vb.net, file, compression, byte

I am wondering if there is a file format that will enable me to store values in the format as indicated below. I want the file format to be as efficient as possible (I.E no extra information, apart from what I place inside it). This is for a concept I have of creating a more efficient method of storing images. Here is an example of the data I wish to store:

```
800 600 0000FF FF0000 00FF00 969696
...
```

I was originally considering placing them in a `.txt` file, but I do not think that storing say 1 million numbers (For 1000x1000 image) in a `.txt` file is very compact.

So, what file format that can be written to in VB.net is the best for storing basic numbers?

EDIT 1: I plan to compress using GZip or some other compression afterwards.

Comment: This is a HUGE problem outside the scope of SO.

Comment: Storing each pixel as a hexencoded string really isn't efficient, though it would give you a filesize that is directly related to the dimensions of your image. For example, your 800x600 image would always be 3 360 007 bytes (which is about twice the size of a bmp with the same dimensions). You could of course just GZip the file afterwards, but why reinvent something that great minds have already invented for you?

Comment: Because I want to do something like this for an IPT challenge (I'm in Highschool :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply store them in binary format. Look at [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

Comment: Any links or anything as to how to do this?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/File-Directory/BinaryWriterWriteMethodWritesanunsignedbytetothecurrentstreamandadvancesthestreampositionbyonebyte.htm